# How can I make border to the text in the label?

Tags: kivy

I'm still learning kivy language .
please can you tell me how to add a border to a text in a label in the kv file
and thanks

Answer (score 1):

In the `kivy` language [documentation](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.lang.html#redefining-a-widget-s-style), you can redefine a widget's style by adding a `-` to the beginning of the `kv` rule. So, in the `kv` you can define a new widget like this:

```
<-LabelWithBorder@Label>:
    border_width: 0
    border_color: [1,1,1,1]
    # draw the border
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: root.border_color if root.border_width > 0 else [0,0,0,1]
        Rectangle:
            size: self.size
            pos: self.pos
        Color:
            rgba: 0, 0, 0, 1
        Rectangle:
            size: self.width - 2*root.border_width, self.height - 2*root.border_width
            pos: int(self.center_x - (self.width - 2*root.border_width)/2.), int(self.center_y - (self.height - 2*root.border_width)/2.)
    # modified from Label
    canvas:
        Color:
            rgba: 1, 1, 1, 1
        Rectangle:
            texture: self.texture
            size: self.texture_size[0] - 2*root.border_width, self.texture_size[1] - 2*root.border_width
            pos: int(self.center_x - self.width/2.) + root.border_width, int(self.center_y - self.height/2.) + root.border_width
```

The `canvas.before` is the section that draws the border, and the `canvas` section is the normal `Label` style with slight modifications to account for the border.

This can be used, for example, like this:

```
FloatLayout:
    LabelWithBorder:
        text: 'Hello, World'
        font_size: 50
        border_width: 10
        border_color: [1,0,0,1]
        size_hint: None, None
        size: self.texture_size
        pos_hint: {'center_x':0.5, 'center_y':0.5}
```

Comment: I want a border on the text not on the label

Comment: I think that is a property of the font that you use. Try searching for an outline font.

Comment: the in-line comments make the code break, but other than that it does what you'd expect

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are looking for 'outline'

This is the docs link for it [Label Outline - Kivy Docs](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.label.html?highlight=label#kivy.uix.label.Label.outline_color)

Here's some example code (color defaults to black .. 0, 0, 0, 1):

```
Label:
        id: label_StackOverflowSample
        pos_hint: {"x": 0.25, "y": 0.18}
        size_hint: 0.6, 0.365
        font_size: 18
        text_size: self.size
        halign: 'left'
        italic: True
        outline_width: 10
        outline_colour: (0, 0, 0, 1)
        text:
            '''
            long long long 
            long long long
            long long long 
            long long long
            long long long
            textt
            '''
```

And this is a picture showing its example:
[sorry, not enough reputation to post pictures yet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VfYI2.png)

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

```
    GridLayout:
      cols: 1
      size: root.width, root.height
      padding: "30sp"
      spacing: "12sp"

      Label:
        canvas:
          Line:
            # value (30) here is equal to padding of parent(padding: "30sp")
            # rectangle: (x, y, width, height), change x, and width together to change size of rectangle
            rectangle: (30, root.height - self.height - 30, self.width, self.height)
```

I figured it out this way. It will create a rectangle at Label position.